# How to select index colum in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a database table Communications with `type`, `value` and a foreign key as index that maps back to a Person table declared as follows:

```
@Table(name = 'communication', schema = 'schema')
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = 'communication', indexes = {
    @Index(name = "idx_communication_person_id", columnNames = { "person_id" })
  }
)
```

And the `Person` object maps to this as:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
@OrderColumn
@Index(name = "idx_communication_person_id")
private final List<Communication>       communications
```

Now I want to create a HQL query with Hibernate, that selects based on this index colum, like:

```
WHERE person.id in ( SELECT c.person_id FROM Communication c WHERE c.type = 3 AND c.value = 'john.doe@server.com' )
```

That doesn't work, because HQL doesn't know `c.person_id` at this point, because index columns are in general unknown to HQL.

How do I properly address the index in HQL, or if that is not possible: how do I write the statement to archive the same as the native-like query above?

EDIT: For performance reasons there must not be a JOIN in any form.

Answer (score 0):

> That doesn't work, because HQL doesn't know c.person_id at this point, because index columns are in general unknown to HQL.

This doesn't make much sense to me.

If you want to have an HQL statement that returns a list of identifiers for `Person` based on some criteria, you can easily do it much like how your SQL statement is written.

```
SELECT p.id
  FROM Communication c JOIN FETCH c.person p
 WHERE c.type = :communicationType
   AND c.value = :emailAddress
```

If you actually want persons, just write the query to select `c.person` rather than `p.id` in order to hydrate all Persons.  In the following, the query allows you to specify a person identifier on the predicate if needed.

```
SELECT c.person
  FROM Communication c JOIN FETCH c.person p
 WHERE c.person.id = :personId
   AND c.type = :communicationType
   AND c.value = :emailAddress
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to use any joins, then simply expose the `personId` as a numeric value on your `Communication` entity without any association mappings.

```
public class Communication {
  @Column(name = "personId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long personId;
}
```

You should then be able to issue a query such as:

```
SELECT c.personId
  FROM Communcation c
 WHERE c.type = :communicationType
   AND c.value = :emailAddress
```

Comment: How is that new personId mapped to the person_id index? Or is this automatic?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM person p 
    JOIN p.communication c
WHERE c.type = 3 AND c.value = 'john.doe@server.com'
```